# Modifying Passed In Object Using Multiprocessing Confusion

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I wrote a function to modify a passed in dictionary. However, when I parallelized the code using the multiprocessing module, it exhibits different behavior then when run in serial. The dictionary is not modified.

Attached below is a toy example of my issue. The dictionary is not modified when run using map_async, but is modified when run in a for loop. Thanks for clarifying my confusion!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from multiprocessing import Pool

def main1(x):
  x['a'] = 1
  print x

  return 1

def main2(x):
  x['b'] = 2
  print x

p = Pool(2)
d = {1:{}, 2:{}}
r = p.map_async(main1, d.values())
print r.get()
print "main1", d

for x in d.values():
  main2(x)

print "main2", d
```

Comment: I tried running your code and it filled up my ram and crashed my computer. lol. I am on a win7 machine, I assume you are on Linux?

Comment: @Onlyjus Yup, I'm running this on OSX. Sorry about that! I didn't include a `if __name__ == '__main__'`, which apparently [causes unintended side effects in windows](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r = p.map_async(main1, d.values())` does this:

**1)** Evaluate `d.values()` - that's `[{}, {}]`
**2)** Execute `main1(item)` for each item in that list on a worker from the pool
**3)** Gather the results from those calls into a list - `[1, 1]` - because that's what `main1` returns
**4)** Assign that list to `r`

So it does exactly what the builtin function [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) does, but in a parallelized way.

This means, your dict `d` never makes it into any of the worker processes, because it's not a reference to `d` that's passed to `map_async`, and therefore `main1`.

And even if you would pass in a reference to `d` - it wouldn't work for the reasons explained by @Roland Smith.

The point is: You shouldn't modify the dictionary in the first place. It's not even very good style in conventional programming for functions to modify their arguments, even if they can. For parallel programming it's absolutely *crucial* to follow a functional programming style, which in this context means:

Functions should do the computation on their input, and return a result that is further processed.

The functions **map** and **reduce** are very common in functional programming, and combined together they form a pattern that is suited very well for distributed computing. From the Wikipedia article on [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce):

> **"Map" step**: The master node takes the input, divides it into smaller
>   sub-problems, and distributes them to worker nodes. A worker node may
>   do this again in turn, leading to a multi-level tree structure. The
>   worker node processes the smaller problem, and passes the answer back
>   to its master node.
>
> **"Reduce" step**: The master node then collects the answers to all the
>   sub-problems and combines them in some way to form the output – the
>   answer to the problem it was originally trying to solve.

So in order to effectively parallelize your program it helps to try to think of your problem in terms of those functions.

For a very concrete example, see the Article [The Trouble With Multicore](http://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/software/the-trouble-with-multicore/0) in IEEE Spectrum. It describes a [method of parallelizing the computation of PI](http://spectrum.ieee.org/image/1627665) that could easily be implemented with map/reduce.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I initially wrote it so that data was passed around, but the dictionary is rather large so I wanted to modify it in place, it seems like I'll have to rethink the structure of my program.

Comment: @user449511 I fleshed out my answer some more with details about map/reduce.

Comment: thanks so much for this! I didn't even consider map-reduce initially, but it actually sounds like a very good fit for my current problem and easy to scale if it ever actually gets big. This paper is awesome as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing a mutable argument in `main1`. But that happens in a different process from the one running the pool. They don't share data.

When `map_async` is run, python *copies* the data from each iteration to the worker processes, which then executes the function, gathers the *return values* and passes that back to the process running `map_async`. It doesn't pass any modfied arguments back.